# Quartz schedular: how do I setup dynamic job arguments

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

I'm setting up a Quartz driven job in a Spring. The job needs a single argument which is the id of a database record that it can use to locate the data it needs to process.

The sequence is:

1. Job starts,
2. locates next available record id,
3. processes data.

Because the record id is unknown until the job starts, I cannot set it up when I create the job. I also need to account for restarts if things go bad. From reading Quartz doco it appears that if I store the record Id in the trigger's JobDataMap, then when the server restarts, the job will automatically restart with the same record Id it was original started with.

This is where things get tricky, I'm trying to figure out where and when to get the record Id so I can store it in the trigger's JobDataMap. I'm thinking I need to implement a TriggerListener and use it to set the record Id in the JobDataMap when the `triggerFired()` callback is called. This will involve a call to the database to get the record Id.

I'm not really sure if this approach is the correct one, or whether I'm barking up the wrong tree. Can someone with some quartz experience tell me if this is correct, or if there is a better way to configure a jobs arguments so that they can be dynamically set and a restart will preserve them?

Thanks
Derek

Comment: Surely you are updating the record with a status to suggest it has been processed already (i.e. a status column)? If so, your scheduled task should read the next available record id, process it then update when complete. The task could fire off every 1 min and only process when a record is available. I prefer to keep state in the db rather in Quartz or my application to avoid having to worry about restarts and re-processing records.

Comment: Nope. The problem is that I have along running process that needs to be restarted. Anyways, am now looking at Spring Batch as a solution. Thanks anyway.